# Changing HTML label in Dagre d3 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dagre-d3

I'm trying to dynamically change the HTML in a node label in Dagre D3:

```
$('.unselected-node').find('.inputTemplate').css( "display", "inline-block" );
```

However, this doesn't work. The only way I'm able to change `.unselected-node` is by accessing the HTML directly:

```
g.node('id').label += "<div>" + inputTemplate + "</div>";
```

This means I have to manually code and store HTML as a string somewhere in a javascript file, which is very unideal. Is there anyway to dynamically change the label?

This is the HTML in question, though the problem is more generic than simply this example, since it happens whenever I try to use jQuery to change dagre d3 html:

```
<div>
    <div class="<%= templateData.class %>" data-params=<%= templateData.jsonData %>>
        <span class ="control glyphicon glyphicon-pawn test" style="color:<%= templateData.responseTypeColor %>"></span>
        <span class="pull-right"><a href="../../responses/id/<%= templateData.response._id %>"><i><%= templateData.response._id %></i></a></span>
        <span> <%= templateData.response.created_by %></span>
        <h3 class="templateData.response.responseTitle"><a href="../../responses/<%= templateData.response.title %>""><%= templateData.response.title %></a></h3>
        <p class="templateData.response.responseText"><%= templateData.response.text %></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm reply-button">Reply</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTemplate" style="display:none">
        <hr style="border: none; height:1px; background-color: black ">
        <form id="responseForm">
            <div id="newResponseTitleDiv" class="form-group row">
                <div id="suggestedTitles">
                    Response title:
                    <input class="typeahead form-control" style="width: 50%; display:inline-block;" type="text" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Describe a specific position that you will defend." id="newResponseTitle" name="responseTitle">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responseModal">Browse</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <textarea rows="10" style="width:90%; border:solid .33px gray; resize: none;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-sm submit-reply-button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried doing `d3.select(...)` on `inputTemplate` and using

`attr.('visibility', 'hidden')`

but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: did you try wrapping your jquery  code with document ready?

Comment: @MinaJacob yes it's wrapped in jquery ready. Anything HTML that does not use dagre d3 works in the same wrapping

Comment: have you tried : d3.select('.unselected-node').find('.inputTemplate').css( "display", "inline-block" ) ?

Comment: @DinoMyte It's not working, it's saying find(... is not a function. I don't think d3 selections have that as a property